# Find nth instance of occurrence of a word in a text file using python

Tags: python, regex, string, file, list-comprehension

I am using paramiko to login to a device and run some commands and then capture only the relevant output. The relevant portion of the code looks like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show interface')
print stdout.read()
```

This gives the following output :

```
Ethernet interface 0:0
Internet address:     171.182.204.207 netmask 255.255.255.0
Internet address:     fe80::2d0:83ff:fe06:4c67 prefixlen 64
MTU size:             1500
Link status:          configured to full duplex, 1 gigabit/sec network
Member of the bridge: none
Ethernet interface 0:1
Internet address:     fe80::2d0:83ff:fe06:4c66 prefixlen 64
MTU size:             1500
Link status:          autosensed to full duplex, 1 gigabit/sec network
Member of the bridge: none
```

Now out of this,I want only the link status,so I did this :

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show interface')
link = '\n'.join(item for item in stdout.read().splitlines() if 'Link' in item)
print link
```

and now I get this :

```
Link status:          configured to full duplex, 1 gigabit/sec network
Link status:          autosensed to full duplex, 1 gigabit/sec network
```

Works fine.However,what I want is to specify the occurrence in my list comprehension so that I get only the first,second or nth occurrence of the keyword Link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've three options.

Store all the items in a list and then use indexing. But this will create an unnecessary list in memory:

```
links = [item for item in stdout.read().splitlines() if 'Link' in item]
index = 5
print links[index]
```

---

Or use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), and pass it the generator created you've used in your code:

```
from itertools import islice
index = 5
links = (item for item in stdout.read().splitlines() if 'Link' in item)
print next(islice(links, index, index+1))
```

---

Or even better use `itertools.islice` with the following generator. Here's I am not using either `.read()` or `.splitlines()` as they read everything into memory:

```
links = (item for item in stdout if 'Link' in item)
print next(islice(links, index, index+1))
```

---

You can also use `item.startswith('Link')` in case you only want to match `'Link'` only at the start of the string, but if you want to match it anywhere in the string then ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just index your list comprehension?

```
links = [item for item in stdout.read().splitlines() if 'Link' in item]
print links[n] # index here
```

Comment: the '\n'.join splits each character into a new line. just print links[n] worked..however thanks for the indexing idea..

Answer (score 1):

```
occurence = 2
link = [item for item in stdout.read().splitlines() if 'Link' in item][occurence]
```