# Write text between second instance of a word and another word from one text file to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large text file but I only need the text that starts after the second, or nth, instance of a phrase and ends at another specific phrase. I would then like to write that text to another text file.

**For example**:

I want the text between the **second instance** of the phrase **Item 1** and the phrase **Item 2**.

**Input Text**

```
Item 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   Item 1   
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.     Item 2
ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
```

**Expected Output**

```
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

The text files in question are very large, so I've been looking at how to use `itertools` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452035/6049154) but I'm not sure if that's an efficient way of doing it for a large text file.

Comment: Why are there two `Item 1` labels, and can we always be certain that the text you want to capture would occur after the _last_ `Item 1`?

Comment: The text file has a table of contents where `Items` are mentioned so it will always have more than one.  It won't necessarily occur after the last `Item 1`.  I'll edit and re-word, thanks for flagging that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `test.txt` would contain the input text, to get the desired output you can use `readlines()`.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

print(*lines[1].split()[:-2])
```

Comment: That might be a solution but I don't think it will do the job I need it to as `.readlines` will read the entire document into memory at once, making it a very inefficient way of doing this.